# Azure information Protection - Rest API

Tags: c#, rest, microsoft-information-protection, azure-information-protection

I'm new to Azure Information Protection, and I'm trying to understand if there is a REST API available to consume file classification labels. I know there is a Nuget package named `Microsoft.InformationProtection.File` which exposes some file operations, but I'm trying to understand if I can do that via a REST API?

I'm looking also for info about classification aggregations either by the SDK or by REST API. I mean, Is there a way to get a list of files (for example from my organization's OneDrive) with their classification labels?